How do I reference all keys of a childeItems in ADF expression builder
I used a Get Metadata activity to enlist folders in a directory. I want to be able to delete all the folders enlisted  .
I could reference one folder at a time with the line below:
@concat(item().source, '/', item().directory, '/', activity('Get Metadata').output.childItems[0]['name']

With the expression above, I am only able to delete one folder at each runtime. I have tried to see if things like childItems[0:1] could work but it does not. Is there a way I can reference all the folders at once so that the delete activity can delete all the folders at once?

If you want to delete all the files under that particular folder at once, you can use wildcard path itself and give * in the filename. This way, you can delete all the files.

This will make sure that all files are deleted at once.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity
